# Regular expressions, different results from code and test website

Tags: python, python-re

I like to use a website to test my regular expression syntax. I seem to be hitting an issue which I do not know how to solve.

Website I use for regex testing:
https://regex101.com/

Here is my sample code:

```
import re

text = "[\xa0]\xa0National Notification Authority, [X]\xa0National Enquiry Point. Address, fax number and e-mail address (if available) of other body: \nMinistry of Agriculture, Livestock and Food Supply\nSecretariat of Trade and International Relations\nE-mail: sps@agricultura.gov.br"

results = re.findall("(?<=\: ).*",text)
print(results)
```

`#results =[' ', ' sps@agricultura.gov.br']`

However, if I use the website with the same re, it returns what I actually want - the address and any contact details.

`#\nMinistry of Agriculture, Livestock and Food Supply\nSecretariat of Trade and International Relations\nE-mail: sps@agricultura.gov.br`

I am not sure what is going on. Is there a way to capture both the address and contact details?

Comment: I notice that you're not using a _raw string_ in your python regex (`r"(?<=\: ).*"` instead of `"(?<=\: ).*"`). The regex website would probably assume you were using a raw string, with regards to the escape character. Did you mean to?

Comment: What do you mean by "_the website with the same re_" and why don't you search for the email address directly?

Comment: Hi  I tried "  r"(?<=\:).*",x   " and got the same results.

Comment: In response to DYZ's comment,  I am trying to get both the email address and other information. If you use the website (or any regular expression (re) website) with the syntax, it will highlight the text I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a dot `.` matches any character *except* a line break. There is a line break in your text after the colon: `other body: \nMinistry`. If you want the dot to match any character whatsoever, you must instruct `findall` accordingly:

```
re.findall("(?<=\: ).*", text, flags=re.DOTALL) # Note the flags!
```